# Is `WebWorkers` concept in JavaScript similar to asynchronous functions?

Tags: c#, javascript, multithreading, promise, web-worker

First I have developed much in C#, now I'm working on 3D web project and now the most usable language is JavaScript at the moment.

In C# until there becomes the new keywords `async/await` in new C# specification there was a way to make asynchronous calls by using:

- delegates
- Begin/End functions, like: BeginInvoke, EndInvoke
- IAsync interface

As for JS... Right now I have a need to use some parallel computations and really need a stuff, which is similar to asynchronous work with some locking models like Semaphore, Mutex or other..

As for async/await... I have tried the promises concept, which is implemented in jQuery with its deferred promise:

- http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/
- http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

It remains me async/await concept in C#:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx

But I've also have found such concept as `WebWorkers`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers

When I first read it, I think it could be also a solution except promises pattern, but if to look from the point of implementing I understand WebWorkers are launching from other threads than a main page execution thread and the functions aren't really asynchronous, they're just callbacks with one option, that they have been added to the `Worker()` instance, which can be used in main page thread, am I right?

So... I wonder, how can I also implement something similar to the `Semaphore` in JavaScript?

Thanks!

**UPDATE #1** ( more a reply to `Doge` ):

Let me describe you a simple example, there is an application, which I'm developing.
I already using the jQuery deferred object for one thing `to await all the texture images I've received, which I was awaiting for`.

The link is the next: http://bit.ly/O2dZmQ

It's an `webgl` application with the `three.js` library, which is building houses on real data (ps: don't look into code, I know it's not good :) I only recently understand the prototype way of programming in js :) first I was too used to C# and its paradigms ).

So... I have such a task. I must wait when all the textures will be loaded from AJAX and only then I'm setting them as textures for meshes.

Right now... When I've created this question, I thought about redeveloping the source code and thought about WebWorkers use.

What have I think first, which I want to do and what I've done when developed WPF/Silverlight application in C#.

I've done another instance of **Worker**, which will check asynchronously the task I've described above.

And I have done a very tiny and simple example which I want to use, but have a fail.

As I saw **WebWorkers** don't accept objects if I want to send it to worker. Alright...

[Passing objects to a web worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704323/passing-objects-to-a-web-worker)

There is a `JSON.stringify()` method... But I've see another thing... JSON.stringify() can't parse an object to string where the are `circular references`.

[Chrome sendrequest error: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816099/chrome-sendrequest-error-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json)

Truly... It's rather disappointing... Because if there is C# or even C++ it's **NOT** a problem to exchange between instances some objects... Some things could be done with some reinterpret casts or other stuff... And it's not a problem to exchange objects even between different threads even in asynchronous work...

So... For the my aim... What is the best solution? Keep the deffered/promises pattern and not to use **WebWorkers**?

The tiny source, not full application, but just for a small example, what I want to do:

- http://pastebin.com/5ernFNme ( need HTML for JS, which is below )
- http://pastebin.com/ELcw7SuE ( JS main logic )
- http://pastebin.com/PuHrhW8n ( WebWorker, which I suppose to use as for separate checker )

Textures for a tiny sample:

- http://s14.postimg.org/wqm0xb2ep/box.jpg
- http://s27.postimg.org/nc77umytv/box2.jpg

Minified three.js could be found here:

- https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/build/three.min.js

Comment: Promises are just an abstraction layer on top of the actual asynchronity.

Comment: Notice that the answer to "Passing objects to a web worker" is outdated / wrong.

Comment: @Bergi ? answer to what? you mean source question or what? and why it's outdated and wrong since it's normal stuff for desktop development and web development is inheriting much more from desktop in different ways.

Comment: The accepted answer to the question you did link. You *can* [send](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker.postMessage) [any (even circular) objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/The_structured_clone_algorithm), you cannot send references (e.g. function objects)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's important to understand that JavaScript **has no threads**. It has an event loop that executes events, one-by-one, as they come in.

The consequence of this is that if you have a process that takes a while you're blocking all execution. If JavaScript is also needed to do UI stuff like responding to user events or animations, it's a bit of snag. You could try to split up your process into multiple events to keep the event loop running smoothly but that's not always easy to do.

This is where `Workers` come it. Workers run in their own **thread**. To avoid issues related to threads the workers *don't share memory*.

You can communicate with a worker by sending and receiving messages. The messages in turn come in the event loop, so you don't need semaphores or anything that synchronizes threads. If your worker controller is in JavaScript there are never any atomicity issues.

If your workers are simple `input->output` workers then you can totally slap a Promise layer on top of that. Just keep in mind that Promises themselves don't add threads or asynchronousness.

---

You can only send Workers messages, that is: strings. You can't send them objects, and certainly not objects that might have references to other objects because again: memory issues.

If I look at your use case I guess the only reason why you might want the Workers is to take advantage of multiple cores that most CPUs have nowadays.

I think what you're doing is loading images as textures into your canvas, and that's what takes up a lot of time? There is no good way to use Workers here since the Worker would need a reference to the canvas, and that's not happening.

Now if instead you needed to do processing on the textures to transform them in some way you *could* use Workers. Send the image data as a binary string, possibly base64_encoded, do the conversion and send it back. If your image is large the serialization will also take up a fair chunk of CPU time so your mileage may vary.

From what I can tell your resources load pretty quick and there doesn't seem to be a CPU bottleneck. So I don't know if you really need the Workers.

Comment: I've made a big reply to you. It's in the question's body, it begins from the `UPDATE #1` paragraph. Thanks!

Comment: "If I look at your use case I guess the only reason why you might want the Workers is to take advantage of multiple cores that most CPUs have nowadays." - truly not only... Also I want a separate logic... I understand that JS just doesn't have mechanism to control/make threads... But I want to make similar to make a class that would control textures only for example... Other class I would asynchronously control FPS, other control other UI stuff (some menus)... It's very normally practice in languages where there exists threading... And it's really needed to make the similar in JS for logic...

Comment: Maybe it would be better to make for browser developers some safe-threading, which also exists in desktop development for avoiding memory issues and other...

Comment: +1 for the first paragraph, but -1 for the second part of your answer. Please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker.postMessage and about the structured clone algorithm, then refurbish that part.