# web worker postMessage() throws exceptions on functions in class - sometimes

Tags: typescript, web-worker, postmessage

Updated:

I have typescript classes that have functions in them and I can pass those classes using postMessage fine. But the following class with a variable that is function fails.

For the code below calling doitSuccess() succeeds. Calling doitFails() throws a "can not serialize" exception. I have also successfully passed objects that are typescript classes that have functions in the class. What seems to be the problem is a member variable assigned a function.

Any idea why?

**Update:** [It might be what is discussed in this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704323/passing-objects-to-a-web-worker)

```
function defaultToString(item: any): string {
    return "dave";
}

export class WorkerApi {

    private worker:Worker;

    constructor () {
        worker = new Worker("my-worker.js");
    }

    public doitFails() : void {

        var ll = { name : "dave", toStr: defaultToString};

        this.worker.postMessage(ll);
    }

    public doitSuccesss() : void {

        var ll = { name : "dave"};

        this.worker.postMessage(ll);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should post the code that actually invokes `doit`

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh - I expanded it above. I've tried to reduce it to just the relevant code. I'm calling postMessage() fine if I don't have a member assigned a function.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the wrong `this`. Fix :

```
function defaultToString(item: any): string {
    return "dave";
}

export class WorkerApi {

    private worker:Worker;

    public doit = () => { // fix

        var ll = { name : "dave", toStr: defaultToString};

        this.worker.postMessage(ll);
    }
}
```

PS: a video on `this` https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA&hd=1

Comment: I'm calling postMessage() fine if I don't have a member variable assigned a function so I know this is ok as is the rest of it.