# Web-worker issue: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Worker

Tags: reactjs, web-worker

I have a barchart made with chartjs in a React app. It works well, but the data parsing could be handled by a web worker so as to speed up the page loading.

I have declared my web worker in a useEffect function:

```js
  let data = React.useRef([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const dataWorker: Worker = new Worker("./worker.ts");
    dataWorker.postMessage({
      msg: "formatData",
      data: { series, theme, range },
    });
    dataWorker.onmessage = (e: MessageEvent) => {
      if (e && e.data) {
        data.current = e.data;
      }
    };
  }, [range, series, theme]);
```

And the webworker is defined in a separate file worker.ts:

```js
self.onmessage = async (e) => {
  if (e && e.data && e.data.msg === "formatData") {
    const { sortedSeries, theme, range } = e.data;
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
    const data = useFormatData(sortedSeries, theme, range);
    self.postMessage(data);
  }
};

function useFormatData(series, theme, range) {
  return useMemo(() => {
   // do stuff
    };
  }, [range, sortedSeries, theme]);
}
```

The worker makes the page crash with the following error:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Worker: function (number) {
> var b = number % 10,
> output =
> toInt((number...... } could not be cloned.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I recently saw this issue when I was passing an object to the web worker that contained a function that I was not aware of.

By the looks of your error, it could be the case for you as well in regards to `series`, `theme`, or `range` being passed to the worker.

There is a good explanation of alternatives explained in [this SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7705809/3550542). To summarize, it mentions passing only the the serializable data to the worker and then adding back the functions (if necessary) on the webworker side.